# CS0103: The name 'xxxx' does not exist. This randomly occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, not-exists

I have researched this quite a bit and while I can find a number of articles on the general issue and the code, unfortunately none quite like what we have.

**Environment:** We have 2 web servers running Windows 2012 and IIS 8. All running .net 2-4.5

**Web Server 1**: This is our main server that runs our main websites and web applications

**Web Server 2**: This runs our client websites

**Code**: Both sets of code are uncompiled. Both the shared code and the client websites are .NET 4 sites.

**Scenario**

On Web1 we have a set of website code that is shared amongst a number of client websites. On Web2 the client site is set up in IIS and a sub directory of the App_code is a virtual directory pointing to a folder in the shared code on web1. We also have another virtual folder that points to the Web1 code as well. We have over 100 websites running in this fashion for over a couple of months.

Recently a couple of our clients have contacted us to say that they are receiving an error when browsing to parts of their website that are served by these virtual directories. The file that it references in the error message is in a modules folder in the virtual directory. it is a .cs file.

It only seems to be one website at a time and if we make a change that forces IIS to 'recompile'  the site (meaning that we make a slight change to the web.config, save it and then change it back and save again), the error disappears and the web site starts working correctly. When we check other sites that are in the exact same setup as the one failing, we do not get any errors and they work correctly.

We are whits end as the issue seems to be completely random. This issue has only started occurring in the last week or at least this is the first we have seen of it.

We are at the point where we believe that it might be an IIS 8 issue and something that might be occurring when it is trying to recompile a client web site but due to the randomness and the 'easy fix' it is difficult to troubleshoot or even know where to go looking for the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Don

Comment: Personally have never done things that way so just guessing - are they all in 1 AppPool? If not, I'd be curious to see how it all works when _recycling_ occurs. When you make changes to web.config, I would think all your (dependent) sites (too) are restarted (?).

Comment: Hi Edsf, yes all the client websites are in the 1 AppPool, hence the confusion. Not all websites suffer the issue, only one at a time. We have had 3 so far.

Comment: Unsure if this will help - what does that module do? File access? Possibly "in use"?

Comment: The code basically says:

string NewURl = EAC. etc

Answer (score -1):

What is the error you're having? Based on what you said, the behavior is random and points on a C# file, not much can be said and only guesses could be make...

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: The error is CS0103: The name 'EAC' does not exist. The reference line and file is in the shared code directory. All other sites that have use this will still be working.

Comment: @IrishChieftain indeed, this should be a comment, but since I don't have 50 reputation, I can't make a comment on the OP.